# woocommerce and polylang change text proceed to checkout button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

Im try to change the checkout text , with dynamics translate using polylang , but i think don't have the good technic for doing this anybody has an idea ? i use the plug-in snippets for push this in my function.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 'replace_checkout_text');
function replace_checkout_text() {
    if (get_locale() == 'fr_FR') {
        return 'Ajoutez au devis';
    }
    if (get_locale() == 'en_US') {
        return 'Add to quotes';
    }
     if (get_locale() == 'zh_CN') {
        return '索取报价';
    }
}
```

Comment: The hook you are using is for other purposes, certainly not to change the text. By the way, the text of the button is automatically translatable because it is passed to the [esc_html_e()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/) function

Comment: Ah thanks you :) not idea how to use but thanks ahah